# Python magic method confusion

Tags: python, comparison, magic-methods

I've run into some confusing behaviour of the magic comparison methods.
Suppose we have the following class:

```
class MutNum(object):
    def __init__ (self, val):
        self.val = val

    def setVal(self, newval):
        self.val = newval

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)

    # methods for comparison with a regular int or float:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.val > other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val < other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.__gt__(other) or self.__eq__(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__lt__(other) or self.__eq__(other)
```

The class does what it is supposed to do, comparing a MutNum object to a regular int or float is no problem. However, and this is what I don't understand, it even compares fine when the magic methods are given two MutNum objects.

```
a = MutNum(42)
b = MutNum(3)
print(a > b) # True
print(a >= b) # True
print(a < b) # False
print(a <= b) # False
print(a == b) # False
```

Why does this work? Thanks.

Comment: It might help to think of `__gt__` and `__lt__` standing in the same relation as `__add__` and `__radd__`, for example. If the first does not apply, Python tries the other one with the operands reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It evaluates as follows (using a `repr`-like notation instead of referring to variables):

```
   MutNum(42) > MutNum(3)
=> MutNum(42).__gt__(MutNum(3))
=> MutNum(42).val > MutNum(3)
=> 42 > MutNum(3)
```

And from there, it's just the int-MutNum comparision you already know works.

Comment: @dust *You* said comparing regular ints and floats to instances of this class is not a problem ;-) `42 > ...` won't invoke `MutNum.__gt__` again as 42 is not a `MutNum`. This sort of confusion is one reason to not define `__repr__` as you have but add something that distinguihes `MutNum`s from the number it wraps.

Answer (score 2):

If you throw in some print's and/or sys.stderr.write's, I think you'll see what's happening.  EG:

```
def __gt__(self, other):
    sys.stderr.write('__gt__\n')
    sys.stderr.write('{}\n'.format(type(other)))
    sys.stderr.write('{} {}\n'.format(self.val, other))
    result = self.val > other
    sys.stderr.write('result {}\n'.format(result))
    return result

def __lt__(self, other):
    sys.stderr.write('__lt__\n')
    sys.stderr.write('{}\n'.format(type(other)))
    sys.stderr.write('{} {}\n'.format(self.val, other))
    result = self.val < other
    sys.stderr.write('result {}\n'.format(result))
    return result
```

When you try to compare self.val (an int) to other (a MutNum), python realizes it has nothing for comparing an int to a MutNum, and reverses the order of the comparison, and compares a MutNum to an int - which is something you've defined.  That is, a single > comparison is doing the > as you'd expect, but it's also doing a <.